# Partial function application with generics

Tags: ios, swift, generics, currying, partial-application

I'm working with an `Observer` API ([ObserverSet](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-01-23-lets-build-swift-notifications.html)) which have the following function :

```
public func add<T: AnyObject>(object: T, _ f: T -> Parameters -> Void) -> ObserverSetEntry<Parameters>
```

It simply register an `object` then call the instance method `f` on the `object` when notification triggers

In one of my manager, I need to hide the previous function with one of mine so I can force an observer to call a predefine function implemented via a protocol.

Here's what I've done so far :

```
@objc protocol Observer : NSObjectProtocol {
    func observe(param: String) -> Void
}

func addObserver<T: AnyObject where T: Observer>(observer: T) {
    let f: T -> String -> Void = observer.dynamicType.observe
    entries.addObserver(observer, f)
}
```

Unfortunately, I have the following error showing up `Partial application of generic method is not allowed`

I've found a possible workaround somewhere on SO which look like that :

```
let f: T -> String -> Void = { (obs: T) in obs.dynamicType.observe(obs) }
```

But this line of code drives my XCode crazy with some `Segmentation Fault: 11` on compilation (and `Communication interrupted` with `Playground` ..)

Is there any workaround for what I'm trying to do ?

Comment: What happens if you declare your protocol as a pure Swift protocol instead of degrading it to an objc protocol?

Comment: Exact same error. If I also remove the implementation of `NSObjectProtocol` I get `error: 'T' is not a subtype of 'inout T'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't tested but you can try:

```
@objc protocol Observer : NSObjectProtocol {
    func observe(param: String) -> Void
}

func addObserver<T: AnyObject where T: Observer>(observer: T) {
    let f: T -> String -> Void = { ($0 as AnyObject).observe }
    entries.addObserver(observer, f)
}
```

At least, this compiles because `AnyObject` has all methods from ObjC - including `@objc` - classes/protocols, as `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`.

So, this compiles:

```
let str = NSString(string: "test")
(str as AnyObject).observe("foo")
```

Of course this causes runtime error because `NSString` has no `observe(_:)` method. But, in your case, `T` is guaranteed to be `Observer`, it should works.

Comment: Yay ! That cast did it. But I don't understand why I have a segmentation fault without it ?  `<T: AnyObject where T: Observer>` already telling that `T` is an `AnyObject` right ? Possible bug ?

Comment: Segfault clash itself is definitely a bug. But I'm not sure about the requirement of casting, it's maybe a language limitation. If so, compiler should report corresponding error message.